# Python sum of number in array, ignoring sections of specific numbers

Tags: python

I am very new to Python and have been going through multiple tutorials to get better.

I have straggled with one difficult problem and found a solution. But it feels, works very newbie like. I think that I have tailored it to answer the specific question.

So the question is:

SUMMER OF '69: Return the sum of the numbers in the array, except ignore sections of numbers starting with a 6 and extending to the next 9 (every 6 will be followed by at least one 9). Return 0 for no numbers.

```
summer_69([1, 3, 5]) --> 9
summer_69([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]) --> 9
summer_69([2, 1, 6, 9, 11]) --> 14
```

My code to solve this is:

```
def summer_69(arr):
    list1 = arr
    summ = int()
    for i in range(0, len(arr)):
        if 6 in list1:
            listOfRange = range(list1.index(6), list1.index(9) + 1)
            for index in listOfRange:
                    print(listOfRange)
                    arr[index] = 0
            if 6 != arr[i]:
                summ += arr[i]
            else:
                continue
        else:
            summ += arr[i]
    return summ
```

It is a very basic problem and I am very alerted that I have struggled with something like this already.

Comment: This seems correct (though highly inefficient). What wrong output are you getting?

Comment: del summer_69[summer_69.index(6):summer_69.index(9)+1] ; sum(summer_69)

Comment: @splash58 that doesn't account for if there's a 9 that occurs before the first 6

Comment: index6 = summer_69.index(6); index9 = summer_69[index6:].index(9);del summer_69[index6:index9+1] ; sum(summer_69)

Comment: @splash58 `summer_69[summer_69.index(6):].index(9)` equals `1` when `summer_69 = [9,6,9]` so you'd be only deleting the 6. `summer_69=[9,6,9];index6 = summer_69.index(6); index9 = summer_69[index6:].index(9);del summer_69[index6:index9+1] ; sum(summer_69)` returns 18 instead of 9.

Comment: @Ruzihm yes it should be `summer_69[index6:index6+index9+1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short O(n) solution** using an iterator and the `in` operator to search for (and thereby skip to) the 9 following each 6:

```
def summer_69(lst):
    it = iter(lst)
    return sum(x for x in it
               if x != 6 or 9 not in it)
```

**Less dense version**:

```
def summer_69(lst):
    it = iter(lst)
    total = 0
    for x in it:
        if x == 6:
            9 in it
        else:
            total += x
    return total
```

**Correctness check** (random test cases) and **benchmark** (with `[1] * 5000 + [6, 9] * 2500`) along with the accepted answer's solution (which takes O(n<sup>2</sup>)):

```
30 out of 30 tests correct

303045 us  303714 us  304335 us  306007 us  309986 us  summer_69_Accepted
   444 us     446 us     464 us     478 us     527 us  summer_69_Kelly1
   442 us     448 us     453 us     465 us     500 us  summer_69_Kelly2
```

Code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVRNb6MwEL3zK2a1qgKNVUG6ZUskDnve696iCFEYGlSDkW1U@uuzY5uvJG2RosjjN@/NPI/dfeiTaB@fO3k@V1I0oOsGaw110wmpQWKHufa8EitQfdOgzOIk@1MU2Gksfa50sPeAvkJ0H6LitdKQAoUP@yP8hCZ/QwXqlHMu3i0GRAUGZZPeTzVH@Cd7dCTmqyuIoRVUQbsiXfbNJ1H3sjUF@Qsk8BaOtsRBVDGVsuw/2KgfB9ew5DNYwmaWbRRQKy/4ShUpzGVxgkpISCCvNEqIZ74S@YroMOXvJ51tdIRrK/8i5x/RysjaGFgTsY15V@0OVnow5tT6whNn3QA/UvLPljeaWBtnPhHdfS@qhc45RUO7WqleHNUAKeldnk5yVR1yhZcIx71NYVj3Z6OeV/VtoUj4dtzYjW83kR3lmymWeVvS3zTFtKLfKzIoTqIuUDlHNCpd5Ar90QYTE/qEUk2RVXljpn8IGZDwjsEjg18Mnhj8ZvB8ZPCWzkJ@FAbOR25vxMQ6m5kZk2boImbgZMwhZnA/JTFIVqvj2jOCe55pQ9khlhILbQ/tKw1XztK4DeLQuTzr/SE8mjF4MKPsB0vJZtMwWtDaHtXzKfkm0b0Nri7qawKno@aMcT0QIvI6WbfaH5MYbESv6dXYMIehgMOOgE0wJtCUu@YOdM3u4SkMQ9haIxOz3lHA@6IN8@YZA91r5/O8eSnz/dwQHUDbNy8o08g15QTv/c1dXEKvYAN34GsSiTAOrFf25imaPXokLXtAJIbvIcvavMEsC87n/w)):

```
from timeit import repeat

def summer_69_Accepted(lst):
    copyoflist = lst[:] # makes shallow copy of list
    while True:
        if 6 not in copyoflist:
            return sum(copyoflist)

        indexof6 = copyoflist.index(6)
        indexof9 = copyoflist.index(9, indexof6+1) # begin search for 9 after 6
        del copyoflist[indexof6:indexof9+1] 

def summer_69_Kelly1(lst):
    it = iter(lst)
    return sum(x for x in it
               if x != 6 or 9 not in it)

def summer_69_Kelly2(lst):
    it = iter(lst)
    total = 0
    for x in it:
        if x == 6:
            9 in it
        else:
            total += x
    return total

funcs = summer_69_Accepted, summer_69_Kelly1, summer_69_Kelly2

from random import randrange, choices

def testcase():
    def others():
        return choices([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8], k=randrange(10))
    lst = others()
    for _ in range(10):
        lst += [6, *others(), 9, *others()]
    return lst

tests = correct = 0
for _ in range(10):
    lst = testcase()
    expect = funcs[0](lst.copy())
    for func in funcs:
        result = func(lst.copy())
        correct += result == expect
        tests += 1
print(correct, 'out of', tests, 'tests correct')
print()

lst = [1] * 5000 + [6, 9] * 2500
for func in funcs:
    times = repeat(lambda: func(lst), number=1)
    print(*('%6d us ' % (t * 1e6) for t in sorted(times)), func.__name__)
```

Comment: Great improvement, I'd delete my inferior answer but accepted answers cant be deleted :(

Comment: @Ruzihm Wouldn't want you to, would make me look like a crazy person imagining things :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it, as a first cut:

```
def summer_69(series):
  in_summer = False
  cur_sum = 0
  for v in series:
    if in_summer:
      if v == 9:
        in_summer = False
    else:
      if v == 6:
        in_summer = True
      else:
        cur_sum += v
  return cur_sum
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version that uses a more reusable pythonic idiom, a generator function, and is a little more compact (at the slight cost of an extra comparison):

```
def yield_non_summer(series):
  in_summer = False
  def stateful_summer_predicate(v):
    nonlocal in_summer
    if in_summer and v == 9:
      in_summer = False
      return True  # 9 is still in summer
    elif not in_summer and v == 6:
      in_summer = True
    return in_summer
  return (v for v in series if not stateful_summer_predicate(v))

def summer_69(series):
  return sum(yield_non_summer(series))
```

Or, in fewer lines:

```
def yield_non_summer(series):
  in_summer = False
  def stateful_summer_predicate(v):
    nonlocal in_summer
    in_summer = (in_summer or v == 6) and v != 9
    return in_summer
  return (v for v in series if not stateful_summer_predicate(v))

def summer_69(series):
  return sum(yield_non_summer(series))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def summer_69(arr):
sum = 0
Flag = False
if 6 not in arr:
    for num in arr:
        sum = sum + num
    return sum
else:
    for num in arr:
        if num != 6 and Flag == False:
            sum = sum + num                
        elif num == 6:
            Flag = True
            continue
        elif Flag == True and num != 9:
            continue
        elif num == 9:
            Flag = False
    return sum
```

Comment: This looks nice, but Flag could be renamed to something like within_skip, to improve readability (and to conform to PEP 8).

Comment: You can also write 'sum += num'. And 'if Flag is False' (instead of comparison) is recommended.

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach is to make a filter and sum the results.

**Code**

```py
def filter_substring(seq, start, end):
    """Yield values outside a given substring."""
    release = True

    for x in seq:

        if x == start:
            release = False
        elif x == end:
            release = True
        elif release:
            yield x


def summer(seq):
    """Return the sum of certain values."""
    return sum(filter_substring(seq, 6, 9))
```

**Demo**

```py
assert 0 == summer([])
assert 6 == summer([1, 2, 3])
assert 6 == summer([1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 7, 9])
assert 9 == summer([1, 3, 5])
assert 8 == summer([3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
assert 15 == summer([2, 1, 6, 9, 12])
assert 16 == summer([2, 1, 6, 9, 1, 6, 6, 120, 9, 9, 12])
```

---

**Details**

`filter_substring()`<sup>+</sup>

This is a generator function.  It iterates the input sequence and only yields a value if the conditions are appropriate, i.e. when the `release` remains `True`.

```py
>>> list(filter_substring("abcde", "c", "d"))
['a', 'b', 'e']
>>> list(filter_substring([0, 1, 2, 3, 10], 1, 3))
[0, 10]
```

`summer()`

Here we simply sum whatever `filter_range()` yields.

<sup>+</sup><sub>Note: a [substring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substring) is a contiguous [subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence); this may or may not include strings in Python.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Will work with indexes:

```
def summer_69(arr):
    y = []
    for x in arr:
        if 6 in arr:
            a = arr.index(6)
            b = arr.index(9)
            del arr[a:b+1]
            y = arr
        elif arr == []:
            return "0"
        else:
            return sum(arr)
    return sum(y)
print(summer_69([]))                                                          #0
print(summer_69([1, 3, 5]))                                                   #9
print(summer_69([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]))                                          #9
print(summer_69([2, 1, 6, 9, 11]))                                            #14
print(summer_69([2, 1, 6, 9, 6, 11, 25, 36, 11, 9, 4, 6, 4, 6, 3, 9, 15]))    #22
```

Comment: Hello! While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: "elif arr == []:
            return "0"" This line seems redundant, and "0" is wrong - it must be a number, not a string. But thanks for the answer and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: However, it must be clearly stated in the docstring that this functions changes the original array. It's not safe to be used with arbitrary (maybe important) data.

Comment: Hi Yaroslav, thanks for your feedback. I did not find any requirement that the function has to return a number and not a string in the case when there are no numbers.

Comment: Hi Alex. Glad if that was useful! I just think it's more reliable to return always one type of result :) Otherwise users of this function are very prone to bugs in their code, or unnecessary complications.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
def summer_69(lst):
  """Return the sum of the numbers in the array, 
     except ignore sections of numbers starting with a 6 and extending to the next 9 
     (every 6 will be followed by at least one 9). Return 0 for no numbers
  """
  if not lst:
    return 0
  else:
    _sum = 0
    active = True
    for x in lst:
      if active: 
        if x != 6:
          _sum += x
        else:
          active = False
      else:
        if x == 9:
          active = True
    return _sum

print(summer_69([1, 3, 5]))
print(summer_69([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]))
print(summer_69([2, 1, 6, 9, 11]))
```

output

```
9
9
14
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def summer_69(arr):
    if 6 in arr:
        c=arr[arr.index(6):arr.index(9)+1]
        for i in c:
            arr.remove(i)
        print(arr)
        return sum(arr)
    else:
        return sum(arr)

summer_69([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12])
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```py
def summer_69(arr):
    total = 0
    add = True
    for num in arr:
        while add:
            if num != 6:
                total += num
                break
            else:
                add = False
        while not add:
            if num != 9:
                break
            else:
                add = True
                break
    return total
```

Comment: Please check out:  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks  -  for more information on using fenced code blocks and MarkDown formatting on StackOverflow and other StackExchange sites.

Answer (score 0):

```
def summer_69(arr):
    a = 0
    for nums in arr: 
        if nums == 6:
            for items in arr[arr.index(6):]:
                a = a+ items
                if items == 9:
                    break
    return sum(arr)-a
```

Comment: Hello! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

```
def summer_69(arr):
        x = arr.count(6)
        y = arr.count(9)
        # to decide number of iteration required for loop
        z = min(x,y)
        k = 0
        while k < (z) :
            m = arr.index(6)
            n = arr.index(9)
            del arr[m:(n+1)]
            k = k + 1
        print(arr)
        return sum(arr)
```

Comment: Hey welcome to SO!, Including a brief explanation is good for the OP to understand your solution, please remember to give an explanation and references if needed.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for summer_69 problem as well for filtering substring

```
def filter_substring(seq, start, end):
flag = False
for char in seq:
    if char == start:
        flag = True
        continue
    elif flag:
        if char == end:
            flag = False 
        else:
            continue
    else:
        yield char

def summer_69(seq, start, end):
    return sum(filter_substring(seq, start, end))

def print_substring(string, start, end):
    return list(filter_substring(string, start, end))
```

### Example ::

```
seq = [4, 5, 9, 6, 2, 9, 5, 6, 1, 9, 2]
print(summer_69(seq, start=6, end=9))


string = "abcdef"
print(print_substring(string, start='c', end='e'))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the probably best answer if you are a newbie. I have simplified it as much as i can. you only need to know enumerate, function, for loops , tuple unpacking,if/else statements and break function.So lets go straight to the answer.

```
def myfunc(a):
mylist=[]
sum1 = 0
for b,c in enumerate(a):
    if c==6:
       for d in  a[:b]:
           mylist.append(d)
for e,f in enumerate(a):
    if f==9:
       for j in a[e+1:]:
           mylist.append(j)
for y in a:
    if y==6:
      break
    else:
       mylist.append(y)
for k in mylist:
    sum1 = sum1+k
print(sum1)
```

myfunc([1,3,5])

Comment: This really has formatting issues, along with the code understanding. Consider adding some comments along with the proper formatting. Use {} to post code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```py
list1.index(9)+1 
by 
list1.index(9,list1.index(6)+1)+1
```

in line 6.
This will start searching for a 9 after 6.

Comment: Please include code formatting in your response and explain your solution as well

Answer (score 0):

For those interested, here is my solution for this problem:

```
def summer_69(arr):
    skate = arr
    guitar = []
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if 6 in arr:
            guitar = skate[skate.index(6):skate.index(9)+1]
            return abs(sum(skate) - sum(guitar))
        else:
            return sum(skate)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is taken from a Udemy course.

Here is the official answer . . .

```
def summer_69(arr):
total = 0
add = True
for num in arr:
    while add:
        if num != 6:
            total += num
            break
        else:
            add = False
    while not add:
        if num != 9:
            break
        else:
            add = True
            break
return total
```

Jose Periera has this on Python 'zero to hero' course.

Answer (score 0):

My own particular approach was this . . .

```
def summer_69(arr):

#first find out if 6 or 9 are in the list

if 6 in arr and 9 in arr:

#Then create a variable that stores the index location of the number 6 
#and the number 9

        sixer = arr.index(6)
        niner = arr.index(9)

#now return the sum of the array minus the sum of the values between 
#index of 6 and index of 9 inclusive (hence the plus 1)
#This way will ignore the case of a 9 appearring before a 6 too.

        return sum(arr) - sum(arr[sixer:niner+1])

#Otherwise just return the sum of the array.

else:
    return sum(arr)
```

Happy to accept criticism here. I'm learning Python myself and I'm undergoing an Msc in computer science and hoping to apply for jobs in the field soon, so your comments will help me :)

Answer (score 0):

My approach was to sum the whole list and the part of the list that we want to ignore and subtract them at the end.

```
def summer_69(arr):
result=0
reduction =0
for i in range(0,len(arr)):
    result+=arr[i]
    if arr[i] == 6:
        temp = arr[arr.index(6):arr.index(9)+1]
        reduction = sum(temp)
return result - reduction
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def summer69(a):
    for z in a:
        if z==6 and 9 in a:
           x=a.index(6)
           y=a.index(9)
           del a[x:y+1]
           t= sum(a)
        else:
           t=sum(a)
    return t
```

Will always prefer short , clear and easy understandable solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
def summer_69(arr):
if 9 in arr :
    sum = 0 
    y = arr.index(9)
    for i , l in enumerate(arr):
        if l == 6:
            del arr[i:y+1]
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        sum = sum + arr[i]
    return sum
elif 9 not in arr:
    sum = 0
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        sum = sum + arr[i]
    return sum
```

Answer (score 0):

def summer_69(mylist):

```
if 6 in mylist:        
    return sum(mylist) - sum(mylist[mylist.index(6):mylist.index(9)+1])
else:
    return sum(mylist)
```

Answer (score 0):

def summer_69(arr):

```
returner = []

if 6 and 9 in arr:        
    
    a = arr.index(6)    
    b = arr.index(9)
    
    if a < b:
        
        seq = arr[a:(b+1)]

        for i in arr:    
            if i not in seq:
                returner.append(i)
        return (sum(returner))
    
    elif a > b:
        
        seq = arr[b:(a+1)]

        for i in arr:    
            if i not in seq:
                returner.append(i)
        return (sum(returner))

elif 6 in arr:
    
    a = arr.index(6)
    seq = arr[a:]
    for i in arr:    
        if i not in slicer:
            returner.append(i)
    return(sum(returner))

elif 9 in arr:
    a = arr.index(9)
    seq = arr[a:]
    for i in arr:    
        if i not in slicer:
            returner.append(i)
    return(sum(returner))

elif arr == []:
    return 0

else:
    return (sum(arr))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Just learning Python too and this was what I came up with for it:

```
def myfunc(arr):
 ignore_list = []
 newlist = []
 for i,v in enumerate(arr):
     if v >= 6 and v <= 9:
         ignore_list.append(i)
     if i in ignore_list:
         newlist.append(0)
     else:
         newlist.append(v)

 return sum(newlist)
```

Answer (score 0):

And another one:

```
def summer_69(nums):
    total = 0
    ignore_section = False

    for num in nums:
        if num == 6:
            ignore_section = True
        elif num == 9:
            ignore_section = False
        elif not ignore_section:
            total += num

    return total
```