# Query on [Python sum of number in array, ignoring sections of specific numbers]

Tags: python

With reference to **Kelly's Short O(n) solution** at
[Python sum of number in array, ignoring sections of specific numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58325254/python-sum-of-number-in-array-ignoring-sections-of-specific-numbers/68975493#68975493?newreg=84e8dcf5aa364a0c978038b1b7d1ef2f)

Can someone explain to me why the numbers between 6 and 9 are not included in the sum? I have tried deriving the answer myself using:

```py
def summer_70(lst):
    it = iter(lst)
    return sum(x for x in it
                  if x != 4 not in it)

print(summer_70([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])) #Output 5 not 35 ??
```

But I still do not understand how the code executes.

Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link to the accepted answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/68975493/3125312

The code in question

```
def summer_69(lst):
    it = iter(lst)
    return sum(x for x in it
               if x != 6 or 9 not in it)
```

Lets work through this with an example.

Say we have a list of numbers
`[1,2,6,7,9,5]`
and we need calculate the sum skipping any region starting with a  `6` and ending with a `9`. The sum would be `8`.

We can start by trying to solve it using a simpler but longer code

1. set a counter `total` to 0 - this will be the default sum
2. set a flag `should_skip` to let us know if we need to skip a number or not
3. iterate through the list and add all numbers but **only if** `should_skip` is `False`

Now the most important question arises - how do we know if we should skip a number? Checking whether a number is a 6 or 9 is not enough as we need a skip a whole section which may include other numbers as well. This is where we make use of the `should_skip` flag. And we need to check only 2 conditions.

1. If we hit a 6 in our iteration we know this is the start of the section to skip. so we set `should_skip` to `True`
2. If we hit a 9 in out iteration then this is the end of the section to skip. we can set `should_skip` to `False`.

We can add to the total if `should_skip` is `False`

Converting this into code looks like

```
input = [1, 2, 6, 7, 9, 5]
total = 0           # The default sum

should_skip = False 

for number in input:
  if number == 6:
    # start of the section to skip, keep skipping till we reach a 9
    should_skip = True

  if not should_skip:
    # add it to the total!
    total += number

  if number == 9:
    # End of section to skip, we can start adding numbers to the total
    should_skip = False

print(total) # 8
```

If you can understand the above logic then it will be extremely easy to understand the shorter implementation. Lets get back to it and start analyzing.

There are 2 necessary things that both codes are doing. "iterating" through the code and "summming" the numbers that are not in a section to skip.

We wrote the code for it ourselves but Python has inbuilt function for it as well called `iter` and `sum`

[`iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) is a function that returns an iterator object. whats special about iterators is that they are memory efficient and that they remove an element when proceeding to the next one.

e.g

```
if our iterator contains iter(3,6,4) 

after one iteration the contents look like iter(6,4) 

and after the second iteration there is only one element remaining i.e. iter(4)
```

[`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) as the name suggests returns the sum. the default is 0

```
def summer_69(lst):
    it = iter(lst) # turn our input into an iterator object
    return sum(x for x in it # add it to the total!
               # but wait we need to check if we are in a section to skip first
               if x != 6 # number is not a 6,
               or 9 not in it # there are no 9s remaining in the iterator so its safe to add
)
```

### Step by Step breakdown:

```
1st iteration -> x is 1 and `it` is `[1,2,6,7,9,5]` 
2nd iteration -> x is 2 and `it` is `[2,6,7,9,5]`
3rd iteration -> x is 6 and `it` is `[6,7,9,5]`
4th iteration -> x is 7 and `it` is `[7,9,5]`
5th iteration -> x is 9 and `it` is `[9,5]`
6th iteration -> x is 5 and `it` is `[5]`
```

At each iteration the condition being checked is x != 6 or 9 not in it? this is how we know that we are in a section to skip or not.

Answer (score 1):

I'll take the code from Kelly's answer as your's lacks the or operator.

Generate iterator from the given list

```
it = iter(lst)
```

For each entity in the given iterator, start summing it.

```
return sum(x for x in it
           if x != 6 or 9 not in it)
```

If the current value we are iterating not equals 6, **the or condition already return True** and it adds it to the sum.

Once we find x == 6, we go into the other condition

```
9 not in it
```

Currently, **the iterator contains only the remaining values** we didn't sum.
This condition will iterate the rest of the values **until it finds a 9**.

If it didn't found a 9, then we summed only the values until the first 6.

If it finds a 9, the **iterator will point on the next value after the 9** (this way we skipped the values between 6 to 9), and we'll do the same if condition again (sum if it's not 6, or check again until we find a 9)

Given
lst = [1,2,6,7,8,9,10]

When we reach the 6, we already summed 1, 2.
Then, the or condition will search for 9 in the remaining list:
[7,8,9,10]

Found 9, and the remaining list:
[10]

Sum 10 and we'll get
1+2+10 = 13

Comment: Thank you v much! Sorry I can't upvote your answer as I am new to this platform