# Python weird iterator behaviour

Tags: python

I was on another SO question here :
[Query on [Python sum of number in array, ignoring sections of specific numbers]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72040327/query-on-python-sum-of-number-in-array-ignoring-sections-of-specific-numbers)

In this question, there was a code similar to this :

```py
it = iter([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
print([x for x in it if x!=4 not in it]) #Output [5]
```

To my understanding, an iterator is like a list in which we remove each element after accessing them.
I also get that making an operation like `not in` will loop over the iterator until it find the value it's searching for. So in the case where we do `3 not in iter([1, 2])` the iterator will be empty since the `not in` have looped over all of it to confirm that `3` wasn't included.

So in my understanding, the first iteration of the for loop should do the following :

```py
it = iter([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
for x in it:
    #Here it look like [5, 6, 7, 8, 9] and x is 4
    if x!=4 not in it:
        # So here we've done 
        #x!=4 => False 
        #then False not in it
        #Since False isn't in it the iterator should now be empty and we don't enter this if
        print(x)

#And there is'nt a second iteration since the iterator is empty dues to the if condition so
#the loop should end after the first iteration without anything printed
```

**But this code output is 5 how on earth is this possible ???

So if someone can explain in details what is happening exactly it would be greatly appreciated !**

Side notes :
I've also tried with

- `(x!=4) not in it` ⇾ output is 4
- `x!=(4 not in it)` ⇾ output nothing

Which make me wonder how is this condition interpreted by python, since none of the parenthesized versions match the version without parenthesis.

Comment: I'm well aware of this and that's the point of the question of why does it still print something when `it` should be exhausted.

Comment: `#Since False isn't in it the iterator should now be empty and we don't enter this if` - I think this is where the confusion is.  Since `False` isn't in the iterator, you ***will*** enter the `if`, because the condition checks for `not in`.

Comment: @TimRoberts No it didn't find `4` with the not in since it's already removed by the for loop who put it in x. ```for x in it: \n print(4 in it)``` This output false.

Comment: No, the issue here is comparison operator chaining.

Comment: @0x5453 I agree with this, but in this case the code should be printing `4` not `5`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, the problem here is the expression:

```
x != 4 not in it
```

Is implicitly chained, because that is how [comparison operators work](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons)

So that means it is evaluated as:

```
(x != 4) and (4 not in it)
```

Since `x != 4` is `False` on the first iteration, it short circuits and goes on to the next iteration without evaluating `4 in it`. In which case, `x == 5`, and it *doesn't* short circuit and it exhausts the iterator checking if `5 not in it`, in which case, the whole expression is `True` and it is the only item in the resulting list.

Comment: Great spotting.  This is the same "feature" that allows "3 < x < 7" to work.

Comment: A big thanks ! This seriously got me to go crazy for the big part of my afternoon.