# Is there a way to get my for loop to work in all cases of this slice?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, enumeration

so what my code is essentially trying to do is return a total of all the numbers in a list, but not add numbers in the list that are between 6 and 9. Anyways, it took me a while but I found a solution that kinda works. But the issue is that if I introduce a second 6 or a 9, it throws me the wrong answer.

`

```
def summer_69(arr):
    total = 0
    index_count = 0
    containerOf69 = 0
    for num in arr:
        total += num
        index_count += 1
        if num == 6:
            for num in arr[index_count-1:]:
                containerOf69 += num
                if num == 9:
                    break
    return total-containerOf69
```

`

Expected and actual result:

summer_69([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]) --> 9

Expected

summer_69([1,2,3,6,6,7,9]) --> 6

Actual
summer_69([1,2,3,6,6,7,9]) --> -16 lol

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python sum of number in array, ignoring sections of specific numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58325254/python-sum-of-number-in-array-ignoring-sections-of-specific-numbers)

Answer (score 0):

```
def summer_69(arr):
    r = 0
    c = False
    for n in arr:
        if not c:
            if n == 6:
                c = True
                continue
            r+=n
        else:
            if n == 9:
                c = False
    return r

print(summer_69([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]))


print(summer_69([1,2,3,6,6,7,9]))
```